# Penrose Tiling Question

Tags: discussion

Would asking a question about Penrose tiling's be a good fit for the venue or would it fit better in the math SE?

It is a question about how to compute the tiling, more practical algorithims whatnot, but I wanted to check first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a question about computing the tiling and algorithms, it's probably on-topic here. I don't know how much computational geometry we get here, so it may not be answered right away.

Comment: I ended up posting it in the math section, as I believe my misunderstanding is within that realm as opposed to implementation.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868115/5d-basis-vectors-of-penroses-tilings